# Powershell with Psloggedon to see who last logged on a remote host (from a list of hosts)

Tags: loops, parsing, powershell, sysinternals

I am having trouble using powershell and pslogged on to pull the information of "the last logged on user" and the "logged on timestamp" from the psloggedon tool. Basically what I am trying to do is to read from a text file with all the list of the servers'name, and then use pslogged on on them to get the info. So if I run the following command separately, it works

```
psloogedon \\server1
```

but when I do this in powershell it doesn't work

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\assets.txt")
Foreach($computer in $content)
{
Invoke-Expression "psloggedon -x -l \\$computer"
} Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation loggedon.csv
```

and in the assets.txt we have the following content:

```
server1
server2
server3
etc...
```

How can i build based on this to 1) make the script work to use psloggedon to get the information 2) parse the loggedon user, the computer name and the timestamp into a CSV with 3 columns file?

Any help is appreciated....

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/17/use-powershell-to-detect-if-a-workstation-is-in-use/

Comment: Hi Anthony, that script doesn't work.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this worked for me

```
get-content 'C:\assets.txt' | % {
    $computer = $_
    . 'c:\pstools\PsLoggedon.exe' -accepteula -x -l \\$Computer 2>$null |
        ? {$_ -match '^\s{2,}((?<domain>\w+)\\(?<user>\S+))|(?<user>\S+)'} |
        Select-Object `
            @{n='Computer';e={$Computer}},
            @{n='Domain';e={$matches.Domain}},
            @{n='User';e={$Matches.User}} |
        ? user -notmatch '^Connecting$|^Users$|^NT$'
} | epcsv 'c:\loggedon.csv' -not
```

another example

```
gc 'C:\assets.txt' | % {
    $computer = $_
    . 'c:\pstools\PsLoggedon.exe' -accepteula -l \\$Computer 2>$null |
        ? {$_ -match '^\s{2,}(?<time>.*)\s{2,}(?<user>.*)'} | % {
            New-Object psobject -prop @{
                Computer = $computer
                Time = $Matches.time.Trim()
                User = $Matches.user.Trim()
            }
        } | ? user -notmatch '^Connecting$|^Users$|^NT$'
} | epcsv 'c:\loggedon.csv' -not
```

if you're using a csv, you would just replace the first two lines like this

```
import-csv 'C:\assets.csv' | % {
    $computer = $_.computers
```

or this

```
import-csv 'C:\assets.csv' | select -exp computers -u | % {
    $computer = $_
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, this looks amazing! is there any chance I can add the exact login time stamp of the user to the CSV too? This is like 99.9% of what I was looking for...Thanks so much!

Comment: A follow up quesition: what if I am reading it from a colum in a csv file called "computers" (assets.csv), and in that CSV we have multiple columns? Does gc command do that ? (select $Computer?)

Comment: Hi Anthony, Everything seems great except the computer will appear twice in the same column? not sure why that happens...